# how to define in C++20 a concept to check if a type matches any of the types in a type-list

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming, c++-concepts, argument-unpacking

I want to define a concept in C++ (<= C++20) to check if a type matches any of the types define in a type-list struct.

The following is my attempt so far:

```
template<typename... Types>
struct TypeList {};

using SupportedTypes = TypeList<int, bool, float, long>;
    
template<typename T, typename... Types>
concept IsAnyOf = (std::is_same_v<T, Types> || ...);
    
static_assert(IsAnyOf<bool, SupportedTypes>);
```

I have also tried using:

```
template<typename T, typename... Types>
concept IsAnyOf = std::disjunction_v<std::is_same<T, Types>...>;
```

But my static assertion fails:

```
Static assertion failed
because 'IsSupportedType<_Bool, SupportedTypes>' evaluated to false
because 'std::is_same_v<_Bool, meta::TypeList<int, _Bool, float, long> >' evaluated to false
```

I understand it probably has to do with the fact that I'm passing `SupportedTypes` to the concept without properly unpacking the types inside it, and hence in the static assertion I'm checking if bool is the same as `SupportedTypes`, as opposed to checking if bool is the same as any of the types inside `SupportedTypes`; but I can't get it to work nonetheless.

Comment: I am downvoting because this does not show any research effort.

Comment: Thank you @Alan. Just for me to learn, how should I show research effort next time? I can assure you there has been... I'm just not versed with metaprogramming and argument unpacking syntax

Comment: @Alan what? The question has a clear objective, shows their initial attempt, and explains what they are stuck on.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> how to define in C++20 a concept to check if a type matches any of the types in a type-list

##### Method 1

You can change the program to as shown below. This is more readable than method 2.

```
template<typename... Types>
struct TypeList {};

template <typename T, typename List>
concept IsAnyOf = []<typename... Types>(TypeList<Types...>) 
{
   return (std::is_same_v<Types, T> || ...);
}(List());
```

[Working demo](https://godbolt.org/z/rqzPaqWex)

---

This is how you would use it:

```
using SupportedTypes = TypeList<double, float, std::string, bool>;

int main() 
{
    std::cout << IsAnyOf<bool, SupportedTypes>; //true
    std::cout << IsAnyOf<char, SupportedTypes>; //false
}
```

---

##### Method 2

Note there are also other ways to do this like using `std::tuple` and `std::inxex_sequence` as shown in [this alternative](https://godbolt.org/z/5fWqvo3nP).

```
template <typename T, typename Typelist>
concept is_any_of = []<std::size_t... Indices>(std::index_sequence<Indices...>) 
{
   return (std::is_same_v<std::tuple_element_t<Indices, Typelist>, T> || ...);
}(std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size_v<Typelist>>());
```

Comment: That works like a charm. Thank you! It reads as black magic to me for now, but I'll do some reading. Any resource you would recommend to get some better understanding behind template metaprogramming or C++ concepts?

Comment: You don't need to use `std::tuple` here, you can pass OP's `TypeList` with `[]<typename... Types>(TypeList<Types...>)` instead

Comment: @monre I learnt all this from the [books here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). You're welcome.

Comment: How do you mean @Caleth?

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/9xr4PWT8s It's the same basic idea, but shorter

Comment: @Caleth Updated. Now added as mentioned 1 and 2 and explicitly added that method 1(that doesn't use tuple etc) is more readable in this case.

Comment: @monre: Maybe the lambda expression in the concepts body is throwing you off ? Lambdas can be templates, too (and even variadic at that). It certainly adds to the special character density in the snippet.. ;)